# Java Server Options

Tags: java

I want to make a browser-based game in Java that will depend heavily on networking.  I wanted to make it so that one player in the game hosts it and the rest in that game play with him, but with Java that requires signing the applet and port forwarding and all kinds of stuff.

So my question is, What would be the best way to design a server system for my game without 
spending tons of money on 24/7 server hosting?  If I didn't explain parts of my question well enough, please tell me and I will reword it.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

A Java Applet is not a strictly 'browser-based' game because it will require the JRE.

If you're intent on Java, you might look in the Google Web Toolkit. It allows you to write client and server code entirely in Java and compile it to JavaScript. I'd caution that it has a steep learning curve especially if you aren't familiar with servlets and client-server programming in general.

Here's an example game made in GWT:

http://allen-sauer.com/com.allen_sauer.gwt.game.hornetblast.HornetBlast/HornetBlast.html

As for server hosting, if you don't want to purchase/maintain your own server, you might consider a cloud provider such as Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (EC2). A single instance will run you $40-$70 per month.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be to make the game peer-2-peer , so that a server is not involved except for downloading the game.   When the game starts, have it prompt for the IP addresses of your friends.   This could be sortof a password into the game to get it started.

Some thoughts/ideas:

```
http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/peer/
http://code.google.com/p/jsmpp/
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jxta2/
```

Comment: And for the vast majority of the users who are behind firewalls, enjoy instructing them on how to poke holes in 'em. ;)

Comment: true, it would require an implementation of UPnP to avoid that.